# restart systemd service if network connection is down

Tags: node.js, linux, networking, service, systemd

I have this unit file running as a systemd service. It basically launches a Nodejs Express application running on a Raspberry Pi on local network. The application runs fine but if for some reason the router or network gets down and back up again, the app stops listening and I have to restart the systemd service to get it working again.

```
[Unit]
Description=Employee Manager PiClock VueJs App
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node /home/pi/employee-manager-app/vuejs-app-server/app.js
User=pi
Restart=always
# Restart service after 2 seconds if node service crashes
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Is there a way to restart the service automatically if the network gets down and up again?

Comment: I solved this by detecting network disconnections in the app. You can call `process.exit()` from your _app.js_ when that happens and leave it to _systemd_ to restart the service, and then your app will be hooked up to the network again. And try as much as you can to achieve a clean exit.

Answer (score 6):

Systemd targets are reached once and do not fire again when the connection state changes. Depending how your network is managed there are a couple of options:

If you already use **NetworkManager** you can utilize its [dispatcher scripts](https://blog.rabin.io/linux/networkmanager-using-dispatcher-d-to-run-scripts-based-on-network-connectivity) that fire on network changes.

If you use **systemd-networkd** you might be able to use [networkd-dispatcher](https://github.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher)  that works in a similar way.

For **netctl** you might use [netctl hooks](https://manned.org/netctl.profile.5) for when your interface comes back up.

**wicd** as well as many others have similar functionality but as far as I know systemd lacks its own persistent network monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

On [Fedora 24 through 28](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-configure-a-private-network-on-fedora) you may use `BindsTo=network.service` in the `[Unit]` section.

```
[Unit]
Description=Employee Manager PiClock VueJs App
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
BindsTo=network.service
```

For more, read the man-page of [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: There is no `network.service`, it is a target.  Binding to systemd-networkd.service doesn't reliably work on longer network outtages.

Comment: There is `network.service`, at least on a CentOS box. It's generated by `systemd-generator` through `/etc/init.d/network`.